# Find nearest 3 points to a given point in a dataframe

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, r-sp

I've got a dataframe with latitude and longitude, which looks like this:

```
x    y     set 
61  -112   
63  -113 
61  -113
62  -111   point 
61  -111
64  -120
```

I want to find the three closest points to the point that is marked as `point` in column `set`. Then, for these three closest points, I want to amend the column `set` to say `closest`. Like this:

```
x    y     set 
61  -112   closest
65  -113 
62  -113   closest 
62  -111   point 
62  -111   closest
64  -120
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
dists <- geosphere::distHaversine(dat[dat$set=="point",c("y","x")], dat[,c("y","x")])
dists
# [1] 123339.4 151513.9 153862.4      0.0 111319.5 505814.4
dat$set[dat$set != "point" & rank(dists) < 5] <- "closest"
dat
#    x    y     set
# 1 61 -112 closest
# 2 63 -113 closest
# 3 61 -113        
# 4 62 -111   point
# 5 61 -111 closest
# 6 64 -120
```

The reason we use `< 5` is that the own-distance (`point` to `point`) will be the closest (`0`), so we need ranks 2-4. This assumes there is one `"point"`; if there are more, you'll likely want `outer` (to produce a `matrix` of distances) and look at each row before populating `$set`.

I'm inferring latitude and longitude from the [sp](/questions/tagged/sp) tag, so chose the Haversine distance calculation since it's fast, and the appearance of coarse coordinates does not suggest the requirement for sub-millimeter accuracy (i.e., Vincenty Ellipsoid formula). There are other distance calculations if needed.

Comment: Thank you!! Can I just ask - my understanding is that the first line of code creates a distance matrix between 'point' and all other coordinates. However, I can't understand the second line of code, precisely what is 'rank' doing here?

Comment: (1) *This* one returns a vector, not a matrix, though if we had multiple `"point"` points then it would be a matrix (and require some more handling). (2) `rank` returns the relative rank of each of the values; since this code compares "point" with itself, its distance is "0", so its rank is always 1; the next-closest will be rank 2, the next-next closest will be 3, etc. It literally just ranks them, from closest (1) to farthest (larger number).

Answer (score 1):

Here is first another approach with `geosphere` (make a distance matrix with `distm`) and then I show how you can use the `terra::nearby` method (which works for both long/lat and planar coordinates).

```
m <- matrix(c(61, -112, 63, -113, 61, -113, 62, -111, 61, -111, 64, -120), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
# note that the order should be long/lat !!!
m <- m[, 2:1]

d <- geosphere::distm(m)
diag(d) <- NA
i <- order(d[4,])[1:3]
i
#[1] 5 1 2

m[i,]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] -111   61
#[2,] -112   61
#[3,] -113   63
```

Now with `terra`. The below gets the nearest 3 neighbors for all points.

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(m, crs="+proj=lonlat")

nearby(v, k=3)
#  id k1 k2 k3
#1  1  3  5  4
#2  2  4  3  1
#3  3  1  5  4
#4  4  5  1  2
#5  5  1  3  4
#6  6  2  3  4
```

With terra version 1.3.15 (currently the *development version*) you can also do

```
nearby(v[4,], v, k=4)
#     id k1 k2 k3 k4
#[1,]  1  4  5  1  2
```

Taking `k=4` neighbors as the first one is the point itself.

To get the development version, do
`install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`